# JQuery draggable - allow containment to multiple containers?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'd like to allow users to drag an element from one container to another while still being constrained from being able to drag the element outside of either of those two containers.  I have everything working perfectly except the part where they can drag to another container.

[View code and result on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoleman/U2nKh/2/)

I thought [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564317/set-more-than-one-containment-in-jquery-draggable) seemed like the answer but it doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a jQuery UI `droppable` to your fiddle. With a little bit of tweaking I'm sure you'd be able to get this exactly how you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/20/

Comment: OOOoooo - NICE!!!  Yes, that's extremely close to what I needed!  I just need some small tweaks to keep the fields from being able to bleed out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

**just add these lines inside your draggable function like this:**

```
$("#drop").draggable({revert: 'invalid',
            start: function(){
                currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            }});
```