# Drag and drop in separate containers, and adjust position of dropped element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**[Edit] : Solution is given in TCHdvlp's comment to his reply below. Thanks a lot !**

I need to drag elements from one container (container1) to another (container2) and back, like in this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/20/

(this was not created by me  : [see original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515569/jquery-draggable-allow-containment-to-multiple-containers))

As you can see in the exemple above, when the element is attached to its new container, its 'style' attribute is erased, and it snaps to the top left corner of the new container.

```
$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
```

I'd like the draggable to stay in place in its new container, where it's dropped.

But if I delete .removeAttr('style'),

```
$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
```

the position information is kept, but is inexact since the parent of the draggable has changed. As a result, my draggable is positionned much lower when dropped from container1 into container2, and much higher in the other case.

I am able to compute the new position where my element should "land", based on the relative positions of the containers. But I don't know how to define this position.

- Should I let the .removeAttr('style') and recrete it fom scratch with new values ? But how?
- Should I delete that part, but modify the position values? But how ?

I hop I am clear enough for you to give me some advice.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully read all the fiddle!

The draggable div has `top:10px;` and `left:10px;` properties. When it's dragged, those properties change. When it's dropped in the other droppable area, the `removeAttr('style');` will remove inline style and set back the 10*10px offset. BUT, it's not snapped.

Also, the draggable element is `position:absolute` but the droppable area is `position:relative`. It means that the child element is positioned relatively to its parent.

That's why, with the original fiddle, the 10*10px position looks to be always the same, whatever the droppable area.

Remove in the css `position:relative` for both container and `position:absolute` for the div.

Remove the `removeAttr` and the `append` in the `dropped` function.

Because we don't want the element to be attached to the area, we don't use `append`. We will use 2 variables to compare last and current droppable area.

http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/U2nKh/576/

Comment: "_Because we don't want the element to be attached to the area, we don't use append._"... Sorry, if I was not clear. In fact, **I want the dropped item to be a child of the new container**, so I can easily browse through all the objects I dropped there, I get their information.

Comment: Ok, Starting from you initial fiddle, simply remove `position:relative` on droppable area and remove `removeAttr("style")`. http://jsfiddle.net/U2nKh/20/